# Associate a method to each item in a list of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

My code returns a list of JS objects as JSON through AJAX. This list is parsed using JSON.parse and saved in a variable.

```
var myListOfObjects = [ 
    {"id":1,"Name":"John","xcoord":23.7,"ycoord":37.2},
    {"id":2,"Name":"Mary","xcoord":17.7,"ycoord":54.6},
    ....
   ];
```

What is the best way to associate the same method to each of these objects, so that it can be called when I iterate over them:

```
myListOfObjects.forEach( function(person){
    console.log( person.getDistance() );
    } );
```

I could define the parameter at each iteration but this doesn't seem efficient and is not easy to implement with d3js (it would require reiterating over the list a first time before binding it to a DOM selection).

Thanks.

Comment: Well it's easy to create a wrapper object for each record adn decorate each object.

Comment: @dfsq Like this: var decoratedPerson = PersonClass(person); decoratedPerson.getDistance(); ??

Comment: Yes, basic idea is like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a getDistance(person); so don't put it in the person objects, but somewhere centralised

Comment: I ended up using this solution as it was simpler to implement. However it is not optimal as the getDistance must be recalculated each time. Wrapping the `person` object in a decorator would've allowed to compute the distance field once and for all at object initialization.

Comment: Well if your going for optimal I would calculate it on the backend so no frontend calculations need to happen.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @dfsq in the comments, a possibility is to decorate my JSON objects:

```
function DecoratedPerson( ajaxData ){
    this.person = ajaxData;
}

DecoratedPerson.prototype.getDistance = function(){
    return this.person.xcoord*this.person.xcoord + this.person.ycoord*this.person.ycoord;
    };
```

The ajax objects are then decorated inside the loop.

```
myListOfObjects.forEach( function(person){
    var myPerson = DecoratedPerson( person );
    console.log( myPerson.getDistance() );
    } );
```

Eventually, decoration could be done in the JSON.parse() step by specifying a reviver parameter.